# Is there a way to calculate the mean of several dataframes with one for loop and then put it into a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

So as you might notice i am relatively new to R and i really cant seem to figure this out.
At the moment i am trying this:

#define the dataframe
overview <- data.frame(

#trying to select the dataframes through a list i made with all the dataframes i need
average = for (i in list.dfs)    {
#calculating the mean of the second column of the dataframe (i always want to calculate the second column)
mean(i[,2])
}
)

For some reason it doesnt make a column out of the info I selected.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `sapply`/`lapply` :

```
result <- sapply(list.dfs, function(x) mean(x[[2]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in tidyverse

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
result <- map_dbl(list.dfs, ~ .x %>% 
                                pull(2) %>%
                                mean)
```